# Sending email without presenting a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need send a email without presenting a `MFMailComposeViewController` In a few words, I need to send the E-mail directly without the user pressing the send button and to show the view.

My code is:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController  >alloc]   init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mail setSubject:@"Recordatorio de clave"];
[mail setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mail setToRecipients:@[email]];
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do you need to use the user's correct e-mail address?

Answer (score 4):

My answer is **YES**, You can send email from background without presenting MFMailComposeVC
There are two ways to do this
1- Either write a webservice that will send an email from background when it will be called.
2-  You can send email by using SMTP gmail account. For this you will have to use  `SKPSMTPMessage` Library. Here is a good  [tutorial](http://iosameer.blogspot.com/2013/01/sending-e-mail-in-background-from-ios_25.html) for it.

Comment: Sure, but you **cannot get the device user's email**.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use MFMailComposeViewController, you can use SMTP for this. please check this link [Sending e-mail in background from iOS apps using SMTP gmail account](http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2013/01/sending-e-mail-in-background-from-ios_25.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `MFMailComposeViewController`

You can create web service and pass data to it and your server can send mail.

Comment: I've always wondered if there's a very simple free service somewhere that just **sends an email**.  So, if I go to free.com/send?joe@joe.com+someMessage ... it will, very simply, send an email from free@free.com, to, joe@joe.com with the body "someMessage".  Surely that exiets ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use `MFMailComposeViewController` for that need to external library or program need to us for sending mail using `SMTP` here I mention gmail thru sending mail without interaction of users.

Code for .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SKPSMTPMessage.h"
@interface mailTransferViewController : UIViewController<SKPSMTPMessageDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
}
- (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject;
@end
```

Code for .m file

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject{

    NSLog(@"Start Sending");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];
    NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"Yours mail ids";
    testMsg.toEmail = emailField.text;//sender mail id
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"Your mail ids";
    testMsg.pass = @"Mail id password";
    testMsg.subject = @"Test application ";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
    // Only do this for self-signed certs!
    // testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
    testMsg.delegate = self;
    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"Some text to include in body",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
    //Logic for attach file.
//  NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"sample.pdf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"sample.pdf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[dataObj encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
//    NSLog(@"%@",vcfPart);
//  testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
//    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];

    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
    [testMsg send];
}
```

Comment: There are serious caveats with this method, that you need to explain. You must use a hard-coded from-address, and not the user's actual email address.  Also that from-address needs to relate to the SMTP server you are connecting to and some SMTP servers don't accept connections from just any old network.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, its not possible to send the mail. In the iOS you can not perform like that, you have to write a web based API for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible the user only has the permit to send the mail from the device. You can only compose the email. If you have to archive such kind of functionality just create it on **Backend** and trigger it from the device by calling webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails programmatically, without user intervention, from an iphone application, cannot be implemented using any of the Apple frameworks. It could be possible in a jailbroken phone but then it would never see the inside of App Store.

If you want control of email sending, then a better way would be to set up a web service (at your server end) you can post to using an HTTP request. If you are posting to only one address this can work very well, although you may want to get the user to input their return mail address.

Otherwise only the standard dialog is available (this relies on using whatever account they've setup on the device).